# Shared document library between two sites collections added as app part

Tags: app, catalog

I have a document library in one site collection and
I would to like to add it as an app part to a page of 
another site collection.
The two sites collections are in the same farm.

I've enabled the library as a catalog and reindexed it but 
still it is not among the apps I can add on the second site collection.

Is this something I can do? If yes, what am I missing?
I would like to do it without writing code.

Comment: Why you want it as app? If you followed the approach of catalog, it will be available to other site collection via search! Do you want to just display documents in the other site collection?

Comment: Actually I wanted to give the other site the possibility to add documents. So, just display is not enough.

Comment: So, with catalog I can make a library available via search only ?

Comment: why not just give a link to the other site?

Comment: because my boss wanted it to be integrated in the second site only

Comment: Catalog is part of the concept, 'cross-site publishing' which relies on search to make information available to the destination site collection from the source site collection(s). The destination site needs to have publishing features enabled!

Comment: It is enabled. Anyway,  if with catalog I can only make content available via search, I'll use some code.